# What makes rollmean faster than rollapply (code-wise)?

Tags: r, zoo

I regularly find rolling things of time series (particularly means), and was surprised to find that `rollmean` is notably faster than `rollapply`, and that the `align = 'right'` methods are faster than the `rollmeanr` wrappers.

How have they achieved this speed up? And why does one lose some of it when using the `rollmeanr()` wrapper?

Some background: I had been using `rollapplyr(x, n, function(X) mean(X))`, however I recently happened upon a few examples using `rollmean`.  The documents suggest `rollapplyr(x, n, mean)` (note without the `function` part of the argument) uses `rollmean` so I didn't think that there would be much difference in performance, however `rbenchmark` revealed notable differences.

```
require(zoo)
require(rbenchmark)

x <- rnorm(1e4)
r1 <- function() rollapplyr(x, 3, mean) # uses rollmean
r2 <- function() rollapplyr(x, 3, function(x) mean(x))
r3 <- function() rollmean(x, 3, na.pad = TRUE, align = 'right')
r4 <- function() rollmeanr(x, 3, align = "right")

bb <- benchmark(r1(), r2(), r3(), r4(), 
          columns = c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative'), 
          replications = 100, 
          order = 'elapsed')

print(bb)
```

I was surprised to find that `rollmean(x, n, align = 'right')` was notably faster -- and ~40x faster than my `rollapply(x, n, function(X) mean(X))` approach.

```
  test elapsed relative
3 r3()    0.74    1.000
4 r4()    0.86    1.162
1 r1()    0.98    1.324
2 r2()   27.53   37.203
```

The difference seems to get larger as the size of the data-set grows.  I changed only the size of `x` (to `rnorm(1e5)`) in the above code and re-ran the test and there was an even larger difference between the functions.

```
  test elapsed relative
3 r3()   13.33    1.000
4 r4()   17.43    1.308
1 r1()   19.83    1.488
2 r2()  279.47   20.965
```

and for `x <- rnorm(1e6)`

```
  test elapsed relative
3 r3()   44.23    1.000
4 r4()   54.30    1.228
1 r1()   65.30    1.476
2 r2() 2473.35   55.920
```

How have they done this? Also, is this the optimal solution? Sure, this is fast but is there an *even faster* way to do this?

(Note: in general my time series are almost always `xts` objects -- does this matter?)

Comment: you may want to try `runmean` from `caTools` for much faster results

Comment: @DWIN i did read the help page. I saw the text you quoted in `?rollapplyr` but it doesn't explain why. Next i went to `?rollmean` and found "These functions compute rolling means, maximums and medians respectively and are thus similar to ‘rollapply’ but are optimized for speed" ... which doesn't explain why either. Additionally, neither explains why `rollmean(x, n, align = 'right')` is faster than `rollmeanr(x, n)`. Finally, none of this explains why performance gaps grow with the size of the data.

Comment: What constitutes an adequate explanation for "why"? How is the "need for speed" not the answer?

Comment: @DWin -- this is a code exchange, so i expected the answer would be that XYZ has been done to speed `rollmean` up, that `rollmean(x, n, align = 'right')` is faster than `rollmeanr` for some good reason, and that the performance gaps grow as task size grows for some other _interesting_ reason. Isn't this place here to help folks learn?

Comment: @ricardo, I think "why" is not the question you're asking for. Either it is "How" or "What makes rollmean faster than rollapply (code-wise)"? (which is a very valid question). Probably you should consider changing your question title...

Comment: @Arun, thanks i've edited to reflect your very helpful comments. I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: To start with, I'd suggest to just have a peek at the functions by doing `getAnywhere("rollmean.zoo")` and `getAnywhere("rollapply.zoo")`.

Comment: @Arun, thanks mate. that's helpful.

Comment: I'd be really surprised if someone didn't know what OP meant because he said "Why" instead of "How"

Comment: @ricardo, when you provide the function anonymously like: `rollapply(x, 3, mean)`, internally, there's a search for "mean", "median", "max" etc.. that'll run the optimised version of corresponding rolls. Else, even though the function is `function(x) mean(x)`, it's not anonymous and there's no check for existing optimised functions. This explains the difference between anonymous and non-anonymous functions. And the optimisation for mean can be seen by just looking at rollmean. Hope this helps a bit further.

Comment: @SeñorO, I agree. I dint realise the confusion as well. I recommended the change in the title to not attract further down-votes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Computing the rolling mean is faster than computing a general rolling function, because the first one is easier to compute. When computing a general rolling function you have to compute the function on each window again and again, which you don't have to do for `mean`, because of the simple identity:

```
 (a2 + a3 + ... + an)/(n-1) = (a1 + a2 + ... + a(n-1))/(n-1) + (an - a1)/(n-1)
```

and you can see how that's leveraged by looking at `getAnywhere(rollmean.zoo)`.

If you want an even faster rolling mean, use `runmean` from `caTools`, which is implemented in C making it much faster (it also scales a lot better so will get even faster as the size of data increases).

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(caTools)
library(zoo)

x = rnorm(1e4)
microbenchmark(runmean(x, 3, endrule = 'trim', align = 'right'),
               rollmean(x, 3, align = 'right'))
#Unit: microseconds
#                                             expr      min        lq     median        uq       max neval
# runmean(x, 3, endrule = "trim", align = "right")  631.061  740.0775   847.5915  1020.048  1652.109   100
#                  rollmean(x, 3, align = "right") 7308.947 9155.7155 10627.0210 12760.439 16919.092   100
```

Comment: There's also `TTR::runMean`, which works well with xts objects.